# Android lollipop change navigation bar color

Tags: android, colors, android-5.0-lollipop, navigationbar

In my app I need to change the bottom navigation bar color. I watched many post but cant find with the solution. I am using appCompat library.

[image]

v21/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bgpreview</item>
       <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/MyColor</item>
       <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/MyColor</item>
       <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
       <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/MyColor</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/MyColor</item>
       <!-- darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
       <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
       <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>

       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>

</style>
```

Comment: can you post the style.xml file? Not the whole thing. Just related snippets

Comment: How can I set back the default color?

Answer (score 373, accepted):

It can be done inside **styles.xml** using

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

or

```
window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int)

Note that the method was introduced in Android Lollipop and won't work on API version < 21.

The second method (works on KitKat) is to set windowTranslucentNavigation to true in the manifest and place a colored view beneath the navigation bar.

Comment: Is there a way to change to color of the icons too?

Comment: `<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>` add in `values-21` folder

Comment: Also make sure that (Target Android Version) is set to at least **API 21**

Comment: Don't put this in your style file `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>` Otherwise system bar coloring won't work.

Comment: how to set image in bottom bar ?

Comment: Thanks it changed but how to navigation buttons color @pankaj

Comment: How can I set back the default color?

Comment: @JamsheedKamarudeen use
`<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>`

Comment: android:navigationIcon to change the icons

Comment: read this very carefully : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#attr_android:navigationBarColor , don't use or remove this  "<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>" if you want set navigationBarColor. This is very very imp other it won't work. Also refer this for more info:  https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge*

Answer (score 81):

**Here is how to do it programatically:**

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {                
   getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_awesome_color));
}
```

**Using Compat library:**

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary));
}
```

**Here is how to do it with xml in the values-v21/style.xml folder:**

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/your_color</item>
```

Comment: This is a strange option! I have an app that makes the navbar black with black buttons making it impossible to see the home/back/recent soft buttons...

Answer (score 42):

Here are some ways to change Navigation Bar color.

**By the XML**

**1- values-v21/style.xml**

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navigationbar_color</item>
```

**Or if you want to do it only using the values/ folder then-**

**2- values/style.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/navigationbar_color</item>
```

You can also change navigation bar color **By Programming**.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.navigationbar_color));
```

**By Using Compat Library-**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary));
}
```

please find the link for more details- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int)

Comment: I wasn't able to use `tools:targetApi`? Is this functionality outdated?

Comment: @winklerrr It's not outdated, see my updated answer.

Comment: If I decide to change the color programmatically - do I need to do this in each `Activity`/`Fragment`? Or is there a certain place where I should do it? Maybe in class that extends `Application`?

Comment: You need to do this in each Activity or you can make different style for different activity.

Comment: No need to override `styles.xml` while using `tools:targetApi`

Comment: No need to override` styles.xml` while using `tools:targetApi`

Answer (score 10):

You can add the following line in the **values-v21/style.xml** folder:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

Answer (score 10):

For people using Kotlin you can put this in your MainActivity.kt:

```
window.navigationBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, R.color.yourColor)
```

With `window` being:

```
val window: Window = this@MainActivity.window
```

Or you can put this in your themes.xml or styles.xml (requires API level 21):

```
<item name='android:navigationBarColor'>@color/yourColor</item>
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Create Black Color:  `<color name="blackColorPrimary">#000001</color>   (not #000000)`
2. Write in Style:  `<item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/blackColorPrimary</item>`

Problem is that android higher version make trasparent for #000000

Comment: If you're doing everything correctly and it STILL doesn't work, this is what worked for me. It doesn't seem to be mentionned anywhere else that #000000 won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Put these in your theme

themes.xml:

```
 <item name="android:navigationBarColor" 
tools:targetApi="21">yourcolor</item>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can also modify your theme using theme Editor by clicking :

Tools -> Android -> Theme Editor

Then, you don't even need to put some extra content in your .xml or .class files.

Comment: Nice tip! For me it was just under Tools -> Theme Editor.

Comment: Now Theme Editor is gone starting with 3.3.

Answer (score 2):

@Zielony's answer above works,

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorSystemNavBar</item>
```

Also added the following based on @Alexey Ozerov's comment

true

but adding this screen shot in case anyone's new and having trouble finding `styles.xml` and `colors.xml`[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change it directly in **styles.xml** file \app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml

This work on older versions, I was changing it in KitKat and come here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set default color of `navigationBar`, which depends on day or night theme, for example, after setting custom colour in one of the fragments, you need to use this:

```
requireActivity().window.navigationBarColor = requireContext().getColorFromAttr(android.R.attr.navigationBarColor)
```