# Change Android nav bar buttons colour

Tags: android, navigationbar

Is there any way to change the color of the navigation bar **BUTTONS** not the navigation bar itself from white to grey:

[image]

to

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android lollipop change navigation bar color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839105/android-lollipop-change-navigation-bar-color)

Comment: I belelive [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int)) is all you need. I have never tried it myself but should work

Answer (score -2):

you can do this in API > 21 as follow :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.some_color));
}
```

see more information [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int))

---

or just add following code in **values-v21/style.xml**

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

Comment: Thanks but I mean the color of the **buttons** not the navigation bar.

Comment: You cannot possibly do it @ZeQianMok