# How to change the bottom on screen soft navigation background and icon color in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to change the background color of this soft on screen navigation from black to blue. Twitter android app has done it. I did this,

@color/colorPrimaryDark

Before adding the navigationBarColor tag in styles.xml

[image: Before]

After adding the navigationBarColor tag in styles.xml

[image]

I cannot find a way to change the icon colors to dark.

Here is my styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/subtleGrey</item>
        <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/myActionButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android lollipop change navigation bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839105/android-lollipop-change-navigation-bar-color)

Comment: Edited my question. Please check it out now @AmruthaSaj

Comment: Still facing same problem! Did you find out anything that works perfectly?@Deepan

Comment: @Saadat 
`<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>`
this solved the problem

Comment: Thanks you so much... @Deepan

Answer (score 0):

```
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorPrimary
    </item>
```

try it

Comment: It changes the background color but fails to change the navigation icon color. This is exactly what I did already.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I got this.

```
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
```

Adding this solved my problem!

Comment: Min API level 27