# How to change Android navigation bar colors with Cordova native?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm newbie. I using Ionic and Cordova to build mobile application. 
I have changed status bar color.
I want to change navigation bar colors. I have search native for that but not found.

[image]

Please tell me native support to change it.

Thanks advanced.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839105/android-lollipop-change-navigation-bar-color

Comment: I have search questions on Stack but all about Java (Android studio). I have using typescript Ionic Cordova.