# Change Android native bottom navigation color?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-styles

i want to change the color of the native bottom navigation of android phones. Like in the image bellow, it's fully dark. Is this actually possible ? And if yes, how can i do this ?

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android lollipop change navigation bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839105/android-lollipop-change-navigation-bar-color)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27839184/10802597, you have to use

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

in styles.xml

Cheers :)