# Change Android NavBar background color with Expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

[Expo allows changing the color and other aspects of the StatusBar](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/react-native/statusbar/) (at the top of the screen.)

I don't see any mention of modifying the NavBar (bottom of the screen) background color to match anywhere though. Is this possible without detaching?:

Comment: I don’t think there is the API to do it in Expo though it can be done in [native android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839105/android-lollipop-change-navigation-bar-color) but it seems lot to eject just to make that change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In app.json, you can add the following (to the expo node)

```json
    "androidNavigationBar": {
      "backgroundColor": "#880000"
    },
```

More detail can be found in the [expo docs on app.json](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#androidnavigationbar).

As of SDK 38, this won't work in bare workflow / ejected mode as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you add a link to the relevant docs to your answer?

Comment: @Slbox added a link to the expo docs for further reading :)

Comment: Awesome! Any idea if it can be controlled programmatically like the StatusBar? It seems like not yet.

Comment: @Slbox A bit late, but it can be controlled with `NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync()` (docs at https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/navigation-bar/#navigationbarsetbackgroundcolorasynccolor)