# Change the color of navigation panel

Tags: android, android-navigation

I am creating an app, with DayNight theme. But, as default, the navigation panel (not from my app, I am talking about the default 3 button navigation panel) is always dark. Is it possible to change the color of that navigation drawer from my app?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27839184/10967323) one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it programmatically.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this of course gives the answer to the question asked, but, is it possible to change the button color also, like what we have for gmail?