# Transparent navigation bar in Android X

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I would like to make the navigation bar completely transparent. What's the easiest way to do this, without having to copy paste code into each activity?

[image]

Comment: Transparent navigation bar? Don't create one.

Comment: Check out https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: @tiborK I have updated the post for a better understanding of what I'm talking about

Comment: [Already answered here. Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839105/android-lollipop-change-navigation-bar-color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For translucent:

In styles

```
 <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

In activity

```
Window w = getWindow();  w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
```

For custom color:

In styles

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/custom_color</item>
```

In activity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.custom_color));}
```

Comment: what would be the color code for transparent, because #00000000 doesn't seem to work..

Comment: My pleassure :)