# How change color navigation bar

Tags: android, uinavigationbar, flags, android-navigation-bar

How change color navigation bar on **sdk 16 - 21**. For **sdk >21** i'm used `window.navigationBarColor`

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27839184/9309845
I think that You won't be able to do it below KitKat.
Are You really need to use sdk below 21? Or below KitKat?

Comment: i need user sdk 16-21. But i don't understand how do it

Comment: So if You need Your minSdk that low, then implement colored navigation bar only for api >21. How to do it was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839105/android-lollipop-change-navigation-bar-color

Answer (score 0):

use `window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)`

Comment: this method for sdk>21

Answer (score 0):

inside Styles.xml,

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

or

```
window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)
```

Comment: this methods for sdk > 21. I need change color for sdk < 21