# How to change background color of software home/back buttons on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

Many Android devices use software home/back buttons at the bottom of the screen. Various apps change the color of those buttons to better match the app color theme.

How can these colors be changed in React Native?  (Preferably programmatically, so light and dark screens could use different button colors.)

Examples from Samsung Galaxy S10:

Teams:

[image: Android software buttons in Teams]

Slack 1st screen:

[image: Android software buttons in Slack]

Slack 2nd screen:

[image]

Comment: You can't change that as those are maintained by the OS

Comment: @KaranMehta Many apps do it already. In Teams the background is black, in Slack light gray or white (depending on the screen), in Google Authenticator white.

Comment: @KaranMehta Please see my answer and reconsider the downvote.

Answer (score 9):

In Android terminology, that is the navigation bar. Since Android 21 (5.0, Lollipop) the color can be changed either [using styles.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27839184) or with [`Window.setNavigationBarColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int)).

In React Native, you can use for example [react-native-navigation-bar-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navigation-bar-color) or [react-native-navbar-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navbar-color) packages.