# Change color of navigation gesture bar and icon in Android programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, uinavigationbar

I want to change the change navigation gesture bar and icon colour to white how should I do that. I tried to change the theme of the app to dark theme but it's not working. Below are the screenshots which I have achieved so far.

If anyone knows how to implement this please help.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

[image]

Comment: how about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839105/android-lollipop-change-navigation-bar-color ?

Comment: It only show how to change navigation bar color, I want to change the color of gesture bar color which comes in grey color in second image.