Navigation Bar showing black strip when bottom Sheet opens in android 15
I am trying to updated to android 15. I have few BottomSheets in app. All of them are showing a strip at bottom which is not part of Bottom sheet in android 15 device.

The current theme i m using for App is below.
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/white_2</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
    <item name="android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled" tools:targetApi="o">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/BottomSheetDialogTheme2</item>
</style>

<style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme2" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle2</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle2" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/top_corners</item>
</style>

I have tried several ways to fix this without success form Here also. Its working fine upto android 14.
Also tried setNavigationBarColor but it has no effect. Also as the doc above says its deprecated.
Any help here would be appreciated.

Did you try changing the color navigation bar ?- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839105/android-lollipop-change-navigation-bar-color

setNavigationBarColor has no effect .. I think u can not change the color of status bar and nav bar from android 15 . but this strip is always at the bottom somehow ..

Are you using edgeToEdge() method?

edge to edge is by default enabled in android 15

Try using material3 theme with below code after enableedgetoedge() method
 val insetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView);
        insetsController.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
        insetsController.isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = true
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            window.setNavigationBarContrastEnforced(false)
        }

with this it will auto adjust color of bottom nav bar same as window color of app,
and don't use setnavigationcolor or setstatusbarcolor as this are disabled in android 15 as per official documents
